# How to start new ASP.NET Web Application using C#

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to start a new ASP.NET Web Application Project using Visual Studio 2008.  The default language is somehow VB and I want C#... I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change it to C#.  I've gotta be missing something somewhere.... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh? Do you have Visual C# component installed? You should select ASP.NET Web Application from Visual C# `->` Web category.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed C#?  Seems to me there's an option to NOT install it.